# Dropdown list not working as expected Tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm using tailwind with cdn, and just copy pasting one of the dropdown lists on flowbite:

```
<button id="dropdownDefault" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button">Dropdown button <svg class="ml-2 w-4 h-4" aria-hidden="true" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path></svg></button>
<!-- Dropdown menu -->
<div id="dropdown" class="z-10 w-44 bg-white rounded divide-y divide-gray-100 shadow dark:bg-gray-700 block" data-popper-reference-hidden="" data-popper-escaped="" data-popper-placement="bottom" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(327px, 70px, 0px);">
    <ul class="py-1 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownDefault">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Earnings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But this is what I'm getting:
[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you include the necessary JavaScript resource as well, or just the CSS?

Comment: @CBroe just this `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>` in the head tag

Comment: https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/#include-via-cdn says to add the script at the end of the body element.

Answer (score 6):

you need to include the FlowBite `<script>` before the end of the `body` element
also, require the minified stylesheet inside the `<head>` tag like this :

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.1/dist/flowbite.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <button id="dropdownDefault" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown" class="inline-flex items-center rounded-lg bg-blue-700 px-4 py-2.5 text-center text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button">
    Dropdown busdatton <svg class="ml-2 h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path></svg>
  </button>
  <!-- Dropdown menu -->
  <div id="dropdown" class="z-10 block w-44 divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded bg-white shadow dark:bg-gray-700" data-popper-reference-hidden="" data-popper-escaped="" data-popper-placement="bottom" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(327px, 70px, 0px);">
    <ul class="py-1 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownDefault">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Earnings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.1/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here an example without library, only react and tailwind.

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDropDown = () => {
    setOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className="dropdown">
      <button
        className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center"
        onClick={handleDropDown}
      >
        Steps
        <svg
          className="ml-2 w-4 h-4"
          aria-hidden="true"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </button>

      <div
        id="dropdown"
        className={`z-10 w-44 bg-white rounded divide-y divide-gray-100 shadow ${
          isOpen ? "block" : "hidden"
        }`}
      >
        <ul className=" z-10 w-44 bg-white rounded divide-y divide-gray-100 shadow ">
            <li
            >
              <a href="#" className="block py-2 px-4 hover:bg-gray-100">
                blablabla
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add import "flowbite"; (on react)
and other you can add script on flowbite before tag